# Url rewrite using PHP code

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am working on a client's application www.islamicaim.com. I have problem in url writing in video section. I was using url something like http://islamicaim.com/video_play.php?id=6 for playing videos. Videos work fine but now according to the new requirement of the client I want to write the url something like http://www.islamicaim.com/category/author/video/title.php for making the SEO friendly url.

I have stored the name of an author in database and name can contain space some thing like mr xyz. While using this name I am facing problem. If any one can suggest me how I can achieve this goal as i am a learner of Php. Thanks.....

Here is my query

```
$q2="select id from media_author where name='".$author_name."'";
while $author_name has value "mr xyz"
```

and I am recieving this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

i have checked this query by running in sql it works fine..

Link where I am having problem is at http://islamicaim.com/media_details.php?category=Talawat-e-Quran&author=Qari%20Syed%20Sadaqat%20Ali

Comment: `.php` does not belong in a seo friendly url. Besides that, you ***really*** want to include the ID somewhere in the url so the other stuff is just for the nice urls but you have the ID to actually identify the video.

Comment: Here is my query $q2="select id from media_author where name='".$author_name."'"; and i am recieving this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 i have checked this query by running in sql it works fine..

Comment: Why you are working on "client's applications" if you are still learning PHP (and apparently programming in general)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what specific error you are having as you basically just said it presently isn't working for you. But as you said the issue is the url can contain "mr xyz", it's probably that you need to replace the space with a %20.

I don't know PHP but I'm guessing that it, like every other language, has a call to encode a url - call that on your url and that will transform all characters that need to be in the %xx form.

Comment: The question above was edited so that this answer now is not relevent.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any problem with your query, unless there is a problem with something else. Have you tried all the possibilities for this? Such as:

```
$q2 = "SELECT id FROM media_author WHERE name = $author_name";
```

Or

```
$q2 = "SELECT * FROM media_author WHERE name = '$author_name'";
```

Maybe you should add some more related code for us to check.

Comment: where does the smell come from?